# Send input value to ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Input with value:

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="1" size="2"/>
```

ActionLink replaced with Url.Action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Shop", new {parts_id=@Model.Parts.parts_id, quantity = "xxx"})" id="lnk">To cart</a>
```

and JS where I'm trying to replace the value:

```
 <script>
 $("#lnk").click(function (evt) {
     var fakeUri = $("#lnk").prop("href");
     var uri = fakeUri.replaceWith("xxx", $("#quantity").val());
     uri = $("#lnk").prop("href", uri);
 });
</script>
```

I think problem is in JS, the value is not replacing, client side sends "xxx"

Comment: try `attr("href")`, doc here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This should work

One of the problems what your `href="@Url.Action("AddToCart"`

It would return a `href` that looked like `@Url.Action("addToCart"` and nothing more. becuase of the `"`

Or you can do this `<a href="@(Url.Action("AddToCart", "Shop ", new {parts_id=@Model.Parts.parts_id, quantity = "xxx "}))">`

^Add `()` around the `url`

```js
$("#lnk").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var fakeUri = $("#lnk").attr("href");
  var uri = fakeUri.replace("xxx", $("#quantity").val());
  uri = $("#lnk").attr("href", uri);
  window.location = uri;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="quantity" value="1" size="2" />

<a href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Shop ", new {parts_id=@Model.Parts.parts_id, quantity = "xxx "})' id="lnk">To cart</a>
```

Comment: is it possible to do that without window.location? cos I have some trouble with that

Answer (score 0):

Let's try different way of doing it, 
First we add event listener for quantity change, everytime it happens, we replace the href attribute value, notice that we should use `attr` not `prop`
something like this

```
<a href="#" id="lnk">To cart</a>
```

js

```
$(document).on("change","#quantity",function () {
   var qnty = $("#quantity").val();
  var theuri = "@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Shop")?parts_id=@Model.Parts.parts_id&quantity="+qnty;
 $("#lnk").attr("href", theuri);
});
```

Comment: tryed your way, but nothing, href is still equal to #

Comment: nothing again, don't know why, all references included