# How to open .NET webpage when add new item button in SharePoint Site is clicked?

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I am a .NET developer and recently i got a requirement to develop a User Registration Page and make it open when **Add new Item** button is clicked in the SharePoint Site. Since am new to SharePoint i have no idea on how to make .NET webpage open from a SharePoint Site.

Can anyone out there help me how to do this or is there any other easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. The easiest one would be to use Sharepoint Designer to create a Custom Action. See [here](http://www.abelsolutions.com/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/) for an example...

Comment: Thank you so much peter,

But is there any way to link a aspx web page to a existing link button in SharePoint?

Comment: You might use a script Editor web part and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) approach...

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom New Item form in SharePoint Designer > List and Libraries > Your list > "New..." button in Forms window, and then make redirection to needed page using javascript:

```
if (someCondition)    
    window.location.href = 'linkToYourRegistrationPage.aspx';
else
    window.location.href = 'linkToYourDefaultNewItemPage.aspx';
```