# How do i add a link to images using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<ul class="slides">
<li class="slide" data-slide="1">
    <img src="smiley1.gif" alt="Smiley face1">
</li>
<li class="slide selected" data-slide="2">
    <img src="smiley2.gif" alt="Smiley face2">
</li>
</ul>
```

How do i add a link to the selected image(class:slide selected) using Jquery?

Comment: you means source or redirect link

Comment: Please provide code example of what you tried.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/179717

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and the `wrap()` function to loop through all images in the list and put a link around it, the following example will navigate to the image itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selected img').each(function(){
        $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') +'"></a>');
    })
})
```

If you want to add a link to another page/site replace `$(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') +'"></a>')` with `$(this).wrap('<a href="www.google.com"></a>')` like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selected img').each(function(){
        $(this).wrap('<a href="www.google.com"></a>');
    })
})
```

If you want to use javascript to just navigate to another website after clicking on the image you you can set `window.location.href` on the click event like such

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selected img').click(function(){
        window.location.href='www.google.com';
    })
})
```

Comment: Great solution! but to answer to the requirement you could try better something like: `$('.selected img').each(function(){...`. That way you only address the selected one

Comment: @CumminUp07: Thanks for you solution, but I want to navigate to a link for example(https://google.com) when the user clicks on the Image. Can you please help?