# Jquery to set absolute path in the href

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

I work in Laravel and have a page `http://localhost:8000/tours/` and jquery script on it. In the script, there is a code:

```
var i = 1;
$('<li>').append('<a href='load_page_"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>');
```

after code has worked, I have a link on the page:

```
<a href='tours/load_page_1'>1</a>
```

but I want it to be:

```
<a href='load_page_1'>1</a>
```

how can I achive that?

PS. My question is not how to modify href (.attr('href')), but how to make the link to be I want it to be when adding it as html via append/prepend/after/before etc (or explanation why it's impossible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: You likely DO have href=“load_page_1” which when hovered will show tours/load_page_1 because that is what it will go to regardless. You possibly want ../load_page1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're wanting is a link to `http://localhost:8000/load_page_1`, but instead are getting a link to `http://localhost:8000/tours/load_page_1`.

You should be able to get the link that you're wanting by changing your append line to `$('<li>').append('<a href='../load_page_"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>');`

The `../` part tells it to go one folder up in the directory tree and link to the specified page there.

Comment: thank you! that's the answer. Though I understand I have another problem. When I am then send an ajax-request (when clicking on the link) it send the request to '/tours/load_page1' instead of '/load_page1/'. Did you encounter such a problem before?

Comment: My guess would be that it is related to this issue... I can't say for sure without seeing code. If you can't figure it out, you can always post another question on here.