# disappend link to url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

My problem is when I change the href attribute via javascript the new href appended into website URL 
[the main link before change using jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FdPM.png)

after i change href

```
 $(".buttonSec").prop("href", "my_wanted_href");
```

the URL be like

[page URL after the change on the buttonSec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqjWD.png)

what I want is how to make this url do not append the link 
using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: i don't want change the href attrebut i already did 
what i want is affter changing this attrebute make the page url like it is even when i click on the button that have this attrebute 
 $(".buttonSec").prop("href", "my_wanted_href");

Answer (score 0):

Try using **attr** property instead of **prop** try the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#stack").attr("href", "https://google.com");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.stackoverflow" id="stack">STACKOVERFLOW</a></p>

<button>Change href Value</button>

<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>

</body>
</html>
```