# Is there a way to change the destination of a link with a click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Something like

```
<a href="www.somewhere.com">Click here.</a>

<div class="button">Button</div> /* when pressed, "href" link changes */
```

And when the button is pressed. the "www.somewhere.com" gets changed to a differend URL?

Thanks.

Comment: Any attempt so far ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: Encap this link in button and have onclick for button, change the link in that onclick

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Select the button and change the `href` attribute.

```
$("button").on("click", () => {
    $("a").attr("href", "newlink");
});
```