# Set href value in ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

I have java servlet application with jquery, in my application I have datatable with movie,

```
var ProjectionManager = {
getAll : function(){
            $.get('ProjectionsServlet', function(data){
                $('#projectionsTable1').DataTable ({
                    data: data.projections,
                    paging: false,
                    info: false,
                    searching: false,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    columns: [
                            {
                            "data": 'movie',
                            render:function(data, type, row){
                                return '<a id="movieRedirectFromProjection" data-name="' + data + '" href="#">' + data + '</a>';
                                }
                            },
                            {data : 'dateOutput'}
                        ]
                })
            })
        }
}
```

When I click on movie column, I want to update href value in my browser with id of that movie.
I don't have movie id value in this table, so I made query to database where it returns whole movie object by title.

```
var MoviesManager = {
getMovieByTitle: function(title) {
            params = {
                'action': 'getMovieByTitle',
                'title': title
            };
            $.post('MoviesServlet', params, function(data){
                //I want to set href value here with data.movie.id that comes from servlet
                //I think it's something like this         e.target.href = "#";
                //                                         e.target.href += '?id=' + data.movie.id;
                //but I can't use event here, can I?
            })
        }
}
```

This is how I handle click on movie column in datatable

```
$('body').on('click', '#movieRedirectFromProjection', function(e){
        var name= $(this).attr("data-name");
        MoviesManager.getMovieByTitle(name);

    });
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) answer your question ?

Comment: use window.location.href to get the url of the browser and assign the value to the same after appending the id

Comment: @CNKR window.location.href was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.href` to get the url of the browser and assign the value to the same after appending the id