# How to search and replace elements from one URL to make a new one?

Tags: javascript

On my site, I want to search/replace for all instances of one URL (that has different IDs, otherwise it is the same) to another.

For example, my site could have the following hyperlinked URLs (they are just examples, again, the IDs will be different):

- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=7
- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=35
- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=100
- https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=9434

and so I would want the new URLs to be

- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=7&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO
- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=35&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO
- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=100&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO
- https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=9434&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO

I am using the following JavaScript code to achieve what I want in the HTML that follows, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? How can the code be updated so the desired result is achieved?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const old_url = "https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=14";

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(old_url);
const ID = searchParams.get("ID");

const new_url = `https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=${ID}&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO`;

console.log(new_url);
    </script>
```

```
<html>

<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=7">This is a link</a>

<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=35">This is a link</a>

<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=100">This is a link</a>

<a href="https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=9434">This is a link</a>

</html>
```

Comment: what's wrong with it? is `new_url` not the correct value?

Comment: @chase the URL's in the <a href are not changing. I'm literally copying+pasting the JavaScript in the JavaScript field and HTML into the HTML field into JSFiddle, but no luck

Comment: How do you expect them to change? Where in your code are you ever changing them? I only see a hardcoded `old_url` in your code, a correctly built `new_url` and a `console.log` - do you expect` console.log` to alter the html elements?

Comment: @chase that's a great point. i need to do something to the HTML elements, but I'm stuck and don't know what to do so they react as I need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

did you try clearing the Cache, if not try clearing it? hopefully, it should work,
Regards

Comment: i'm doing this on a fiddle to avoid caching issues

Answer (score 0):

The following may work for what you are trying to achieve here:

```js
const old_url = "https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=14";

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(old_url).search);
const ID = searchParams.get("ID");

const new_url = `https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=${ID}&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO`;
// Another way to do this
const new_url_alt = new URL('https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=${ID}&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO');
search_params_new.set('ID', ID);
new_url_alt.search = search_params_new;

console.log(new_url);
console.log(new_url_alt); // Same result

document.querySelectorAll(`a[href="${old_url}"]`).forEach(elem => elem.href = new_url); // Or new_url_alt; Both shall work
```

Comment: The URLs in the <a href's are not being rewritten. I'm just copying+pastin the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mike Oh! If that is what you are looking for, I'll update my answer.