# Using anchor tag href value as a input type file

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an anchor tag as below:

```
<a id="link" style="display:none" target="_blank">View Certificate</a>
```

`href` value gets appended to the above tag in JQuery dynamically.

Now when I click a button, my certificate in anchor tag should save as a file using `file.saveas(path,certificate)` in controller method `insert()`

Please suggest on how to perform the above action using JQuery and C#.

Comment: Take a look at this post: [SO - How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: Take a look at this: [SO - How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: You want to set input type file value via jquery ?

Comment: You want to get or set the html or text of html elements with link id?  Maybe use attr?  I think your not being clear of where you get the value for path and certificate.  show more html maybe? Or more javascript?